# a @Endpoint annotated class handling requests from multiple clients, can it be asynchronous?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, synchronous

In one of the Spring projects I am working on there is a class annotated with @Endpoint, and the methods are annotated with @PayloadRoot. It appears to me that it works in such a way that the requests are handled synchronously and next request won't be dealt with till a response to the earlier request has been returned.

How can we improve performance in a scenario that there are requests coming in from multiple clients?

thanks,
John

Comment: What makes you think that requests are handled synchronously?

Comment: thanks shazin. It's not what i think - it's how it's coded: for example, one of the methods in the Endpoint class takes the request and uses it to retrieve data from a DB to form a response, the whole process is blocked till the response is generated. The log file confirmed that no new request till the previous response returns.

Answer (score 2):

Each @Endpoint class are scoped as singleton and could handle requests coming from multiple clients, so each one has it's one thread.

Check Note in http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/server.html :

> Endpoints, like any other Spring Bean, are scoped as a singleton by
>   default, i.e. one instance of the bean definition is created per
>   container. Being a singleton implies that more than one thread can use
>   it at the same time, so the endpoint has to be thread safe. If you
>   want to use a different scope, such as prototype, refer to the Spring
>   Reference documentation.
>
> Note that all abstract base classes provided in Spring-WS are thread
>   safe, unless otherwise indicated in the class-level Javadoc.

Comment: Thanks Patrick. I've read the document. Will it help if I scope the Endpoint to be prototype? Will it lose its thread safety? Can we know how many instances will be created by the Spring container? If a request comes in, will all Endpoint instances handle it or just one of them does? The transport in this project is a JMS. Sorry for all the questions, any help is appreciated...